# How to create exe files from Python 3.6 script?

Tags: exe, python-3.6

I want to learn if is there any available wheel for Python 3.6 to create executable files. I know pyinstall cx_freeze and py2exe options. However, they are available for Python3.4 or 3.5 for the most uptaded. Is there any way to create .exe from Python 3.6 script?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used cx_freeze 5.0.1 with Python 3.6. Did you tried with older version or specific setup that failed ?

Comment: I indeed tried cx_freeze but that did not have x64 compatibility. For x86 platforms freezer looks worked good but I could not find for x64 bit version. By the way I have not tried older versions